# Copy assignment explanation (C++)

Tags: c++

Here is the code of copy assignment and move assignment for Vector class:

```
//Copy assignment

Vector& Vector::operator = (const Vector& other)
        {
            double* p = new double[other.size];
            copy(other.elem,other.elem + other.size,elem);
            delete[] elem;
            elem = p;
            size = other.size;
            return *this
        }
```

Here is how I understood Copy assignment:

```
double* p = new double[other.size];
```

- means, that we allocate new space for our new vector

```
copy(other.elem,other.elem + other.size,elem);
```

- we copy all elements of `other` vector(from first element `other.elem` to the last element `other.elem + other.size`) to the space p?

```
delete[] elem;
```

-we deallocate old space, because we will substitute it by new one

```
elem = p;
size = other.size;
return *this
```

- We substitute parameters by new parameters and return them

is my understanding correct?

What I don't understand(or at least for now my brain cannot accept it), that if we deallocate old space, why is it possible to allocate new elements to it?

Comment: Regarding the `copy` call, your understanding is wrong. Do you see `p` used anywhere in the call?

Comment: I also recommend you check [this canonical implementation of the copy-assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator). Pay close attention to the first statement in that function (the `if`). You bypass that problem because of the order you do things, but you still do operations you don't have to do if you assign the object to itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is used in assigning elem = p

Comment: Yes, but you don't *copy* from the other to `p`. You copy to `elem`. Which can lead to some big problems if `this->sz < other.sz`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this code is actually from programming principles and practices using c++ Stroustrup. And as you understood I didn't get the idea. If you hava time, can you explain step by step the meaning of each line?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I corrected size - sz variable names. It was a typo

Comment: You have to copy into p, not elem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
double* p = new double[other.size];
```

you allocate memory for the new "array", and make `p` point to it. Then with

```
 copy(other.elem,other.elem + other.size,elem);
```

you copy to the ***old*** "array", as the destination is `elem` instead of `p`.

It should really be

```
 copy(other.elem,other.elem + other.size,p);
```

---

Unless you made a mistake copying from the book, this is really something that should be pointed out to Stroustrup, as I can't find anything about it in the errata for any edition or printing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did copy it correctly, as I spoted there are many typos in the second edition of his book

Answer (score 0):

given:

- Vector::elem is a value of type double*
- Vector::size is a value of some integer type (say int)

Then your understanding is correct.

Remember that the member variable `elem` has two functions - one is to point to the sequence of doubles, the second is to actually 'own' the memory which has been allocated.

So the sequence is:

```
// allocate a sequence large enough, make p point to it
double* p = new double[other.size]; 

// delete our existing elem. i.e. destruct all items in 
// the sequence and free the memory containing the sequence.
delete[] elem;

// at this point p is valid and elem is pointing to memory we no longer own

// make elem point to the newly allocated sequence, p
elem = p;

// at this point, both p and elem point to the new sequence of doubles.
// p will drop out of scope, but since it's a raw pointer, this has
// no effect on the memory it was pointing at.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I have another question: should I copy to the new array? 'copy(other.elem,other.elem + other.size,p)'